# how to hide Tabbar when navigating to another page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
const FriendListStackNav = createStackNavigator({
    FriendList: {
        screen: FriendList,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    Chat: Chat
});

const TabNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomePage,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <Icon name='home' color={tintColor} size={25} />
            )
        }
    },
    FriendList: {
        screen: FriendListStackNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <Icon name='inbox' color={tintColor} size={25} />
            )
        }
    }
}, {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'rgb(0, 206, 209)',
        inactiveTintColor: 'rgb(128, 128, 128)',
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: false,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
        },
        indicatorStyle: {
            height: 0 
        }
    }
});

export default createStackNavigator({
    SignIn: SignIn,
    Home: {
        screen: TabNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    Folowing: Folowing,
    Folowers: Folowers
});
```

Hi, I have StakNavigator in TabNavigator, when i go to the Chat page, the tabbar is shown below.
How to hide tabBar on Chat page ? 
I have stackNavigator at the beginning after tabNavigator goes, then another stackNavigator.
[this is a Homepage, with TabNavigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rS3O.png)

[when press in icon, i go to chat page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtoeq.png)

[how to hide tabbar in this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIk3Z.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you're using react navigation v3 , then you can try this.

```
FriendListStackNav.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let tabBarVisible = true;
  if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    tabBarVisible = false;
  }

  return {
    tabBarVisible,
  };
};
```